# How to retrive all comments for a specific post?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

Having a bit of block trying to get comments for a specific post. Working with MVC 3 and VBNET. A post url looks like /Blog/Post/1. I can display the post without problem but need to get the comments for PostId=1 from the Comments table. I tried a Linq inner join statement

```
Dim results = From P In _rdsqlconn.Posts Where P.PostId = id Join c In _rdsqlconn.Comments On P.PostId Equals c.PostId Select P



Public Class RDSQLConn
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub


        Property Posts As DbSet(Of Post)
        Property Categories As DbSet(Of Category)
        Property Comments As DbSet(Of Comment)

    End Class
```

But this throws:

```
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post]' to type 'RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post'.`
```

However  a SQL query such as the one below works just fine. Can i just pass in this sql statement to my EF?

```
Select * From Posts  INNER JOIN Comments on dbo.Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId where dbo.Posts.PostId = 1
```

Comment: Why do you execute join manually? If your post is correctly mapped with navigation property to Comments you can just use eager loading (`Include`) method to load comments.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, does the navigation property only work if i have an edmx file? I just have my entities and the DBContext class.

Comment: Hi Ashok. It's been awhile. I assume you found out about navigation properties, fluent mapping and stuff in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim results = From P In _rdsqlconn.Posts Join c In _rdsqlconn.Comments On P.PostId Equals c.PostId 
Where P.PostId = id 
Select P
```

Comment: i tried the linq statement you provided but it still throws Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post]' to type 'RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post'.